# Deployment discriptor or web.xml

Tags: java, web.xml, deployment-descriptor

I was learning concept of servlet and JSP. When I created a web.xml file in my project, my output is as follows.
[image: web.xml-created by me]

whereas, in the course am following it appears like this.

[image: web.xml - as per online tutorial]

Please let me know, what's the difference between both of them and how to edit the web.xml file created by me to define servlet.

Comment: You are using the IDE's default XML formatter whereas the course shows the source file. You can edit from both the formatter in your IDE or by switching to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the `Source` tab. You will find the web.xml file in your desired format.

[image: Web.xml]